# C# string problems

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have a multiline text box called `txtOutput` that receives messages from the serial port. Each new message is a new line and represents a number from 1 to a maximum of 4 digits.
The method used to add the data in the multiline textbox is an append.
I have no problems with the above feature, it is working fine.

I would like to take the last message from the `txtOutput` and show it in `textBox2` if the number is less than 1000, and in `textbox3` if it is not. Then both text boxes would be updated.

I would appreciate if someone can give in an example especially in how to get the *last* message from the multiline textbox to a variable and how to update the textboxes if there is a new value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all for the suggestions but as I mentioned in my comments, the suggested methods did not work because the content of the string was not accurate and I ended up receiving in the textBox 2 and 3 only part of the data and not always. I have solved the problem (thanks to other advices) using RegEx in this way:

```
 if (txtOutput.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(txtOutput.Text, @"(\+|-)?\d+");
            if (mc.Count > 0)
            {
                long value = long.Parse(mc[mc.Count - 1].Value);
                if (value < 1000)
                {
                    textBox2.Text = value.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    value = value - 1000;
                    textBox3.Text = value.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
```

this is working fine and no piece of information are lost.Thanks again for your advices.

Answer (score 3):

You should save the last message (from the serial port) in a variable such as `lastSerialMesssage`.  You can then convert this value to an integer and use a `conditional statement` to check if the value is smaller than 1000, if it is, set `TextBox3` to the last serial message value, else set the value to `TextBox2`.

```
string lastSerialMessage = SerialPortMessage;

int lastMessageValue;
Int32.TryParse(lastSerialMessage, out lastMessageValue);

if (lastMessageValue < 1000)
{
   TextBox3.Text = lastSerialMessage;
} else {
   TextBox2.Text = lastSerialmessage;
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx

Comment: Hi guys, both of your methods gives me the same result. The textbox 2 and 3 are updated but not every time that a message is received.Moreover sometime only part of the message is shown in the textbox 2 and 3 (if I have 1231 in the txtOutput, I may get only 31 or 1 in the text box 3 or 2.

Comment: I should have posted it before. This is how I get the message from serial to txtOutput textbox.                                               delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);
        private void SetText(string text)
        {
            if (this.txtOutput.InvokeRequired)
            {
                SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
                this.BeginInvoke(d, new object[] { text });
            }
            else
            {
                txtOutput.AppendText(text);
            }}

Comment: private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
                {
           
                    try
                    {
                        SetText(serialPort1.ReadExisting());
                    }

                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        SetText(ex.ToString());
                    }

             }